# compare more than 2 proportions matlab

Tags: matlab, comparison, chi-squared, significance

Having 4 groups (A,B,C,D)
each of them containing a different number of male and female

```
male_A = 46
male_B = 241
male_C = 202
male_D = 113

female_A = 43
female_B = 134
female_C = 100
female_D = 53
```

How can I identify the groups that have a statistically different proportion of male and female? Suggestion using MATLAB would be appreciated...

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION (PLEASE CHECK)**

```
% 1st row: male
% 2nd row: female
cont = [46   241   202   113;
        43   134   100    53]

mychi(cont)


%this function should calculate the Chi2 
function mychi(cont)
    cont = [cont, sum(cont,2)];
    cont = [cont; sum(cont,1)];

    counter = 1;
    for i = 1 : size(cont,1)-1

        for j = 1 : size(cont,2)-1

            Observed(counter) = cont(i,j);
            Expected(counter) = cont(i,end)*cont(end,j)/cont(end:end);
            O_E_2(counter) = (abs(Observed(counter)-Expected(counter)).^2)/Expected(counter);
            counter = counter + 1;
        end

    end

    DOF = (size(cont,1)-2)*(size(cont,2)-2)
    CHI = sum(O_E_2)
end
```

The CHI returned should be compared with the one for p<0.05 that can be found [here](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/tbl-chi.html)

In my case

```
DOF =

     3


CHI =

    8.0746
```

CHI is > 0.352 so the groups have a biased number of male and female...

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean exactly by "statistically different proportion"?

Comment: that the hypothesis that proportion A is different from proportion B, C, D etc. using some statistical test (I am looking for the right one) for some p<0.05

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value

Comment: Documentation: http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/hypothesis-testing.html

Comment: Please do not spam, my problem is different from the one you sent. In particular: 1) I have categorical variables, 2) I have more than 2 groups, 3) the groups have different size

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what comparison you are looking for, but the ratios can be obtained by

```
p = 0.05;

ratio_A = male_A ./ (male_A + female_A);
ratio_B = male_B ./ (male_B + female_B);
ratio_C = male_C ./ (male_C + female_C);
ratio_D = male_D ./ (male_D + female_D);
```

%Once you have ratios, you can perform analysis as mentioned on
   %http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/hypothesis-testing.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to arrange your data in a matrix and use the proper indexing according to your pourposes. Here you have an example:

```
male_A = 46;
male_B = 241;
male_C = 202;
male_D = 113;

female_A = 43;
female_B = 134;
female_C = 100;
female_D = 53;

matrix = [male_A female_A;
    male_B female_B;
    male_C female_C;
    male_D female_D];

groups = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

total = (matrix(:,1)+matrix(:,2));
male_percentage = matrix(:,1)./total*100
female_percentage = matrix(:,2)./total*100

threshold = 65;   %// Example threshold 65%
male_above_threshold = groups(male_percentage>threshold)
female_above_threshold = groups(female_percentage>threshold)

maximum_male_ratio = groups(male_percentage==max(male_percentage))
maximum_female_ratio = groups(female_percentage==max(female_percentage))
```

In your example you would get:

```
male_percentage =

   51.6854
   64.2667
   66.8874
   68.0723


female_percentage =

   48.3146
   35.7333
   33.1126
   31.9277


male_above_threshold =

CD


female_above_threshold =

   Empty string: 1-by-0



maximum_male_ratio =

D


maximum_female_ratio =

A
```

Finding out the groups that are statistically different is another problem. You should provide more information in order to do that.

Comment: My problem is that one...not how to compute the ratio...which kind of info would you like to have?  I think the problem is well defined..